# Need to remove all AlphaNumeric characters from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array like this ,i want to strip all alpha characters.

```
 $testString = Array ([0] => 46_xsdfdsa_ddasdasd [1] => 23423_wrwerwer_ajbfdahbfkahflagassl);
    echo preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $testString);
```

Output should be 46,23423.

I tried above and it did n't work.

Thanks in-advance

Comment: alphanumeric means containing letters and numbers. you want to get numbers and drop letters, huh? correct your grammar mistakes.

Comment: And what was the output? At a glance, you appear to be missing the alphabet class ([a-zA-Z] or something like that) from your regular expression.

Comment: @deporter:Thanks for point it out,it was a typos.updated my question,i want only number's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
echo preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $testString);
```

FYI, alphanumeric means alpha + numeric characters. From your question title, you seem to suggest that you want to replace them all. Let's know if this works for you.

---

If in the output you only want numbers, `,.`, this is what you would do:

```
echo preg_replace("/[^\d,.]/", "", $testString);
```

**Example:**

```
$str = '23,423_.wrwerwer_ajbfdahbfkahflagassl';
echo preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $str); // result: 23,423.
```

#### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/nMoMP9Ds)

Comment: :I get this error on line 1
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Comment: @user1051322: I have provided link to working example. As for loop, you can use `foreach` to loop over array and then apply above code to it to replace characters. If you can not figure out how to do it for loop, you can ask another question for that.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
$testString = array(0 => '46_xsdfdsa_ddasdasd', 1 => '23423_wrwerwer_ajbfdahbfkahflagassl');
echo join(",",preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $testString));
```

The regexp you have works - you just need to join up the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $testString);
$string = implode(",", $array);
```

If you pass array to `preg_replace` it will return you array and not string ,so you need to impload the data to make it as string

Answer (score 0):

```
$testString = Array ( "0" => "46_xsdfdsa_ddasdasd" , "1" =>   "23423_wrwerwer_ajbfdahbfkahflagassl");
$result = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $testString);
print_r ($result);
```

Its working !!