# How do I remove alphanumeric characters from a text file in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a huge text file, and I want to remove everything that isn't a symbol (for example - , . ' "), how do I remove everything so that the only things that are left is symbols, without specifying what symbols to keep.

As an example

> "There's a man outside.  He's come to take you away!"

would leave you with "'.'!"

Comment: You are looking for http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Duplicate of question [Removing Non Alphanumeric Characters With PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659025/removing-non-alphanumeric-characters-with-php?rq=1) (Just the other way around)

Comment: Duplicate: [Need to remove all AlphaNumeric characters from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9408808/938236)

Comment: You were faster @Overv

Comment: So.... do accented characters count as alphanumeric or symbols?

Comment: @Spudley , and what about the ñ? Here in Spain that's a letter. But then, α is used as a symbol in Mathematics and as a letter in Greek

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions:

```
$outputText = preg_replace('/[a-z0-9]+/Ui', '', $inputText);
```

Comment: What is the difference between preg_replace and str_replace?
Is it better practice to use one over the other?

Comment: with `preg_replace`, you can use regular expressions. If you don't know what a RegEx is, I suggest you to find out, for it is way more powerfull than simple text search and replace, by far. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/[A-Za-z0-9+]/", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested, just freestyled into this window here):

`implode('', array_filter(str_split([.. your string ..]), function ($char) { return !ctype_alnum($char); }));`

Answer (score 0):

I went with

```
$symbCount = preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9+]/', '', $fileStr);
```

Thanks